# How to connect Sharepoint database to Rstudio Server?

Tags: connection, sharepoint-online, rstudio-server

Recently my company is planning to migrate the current data working process to server.

The current way:

- Database: Sharepoint
- Tool: Rstudio Desktop
- The syntax to connect Sharepoint to Rstudio desktop:

path_me <- "C:/Users/[MY WORK USERNAME]/OneDrive - [COMPANY NAME]/Documents - [DATABASE NAME]/[FOLDER A]/[FOLDER B]/[FOLDER C]"

file_I_need <- read_csv(paste(path_me ,"file_I_need.csv", sep = "/"))
filename <- read_csv(paste(path_data,"file_I_need.csv", sep = "/"))

The wanted way:

- Database: Sharepoint Online
- Tool: Rstudio Server

How to do so? I am using a Window laptop.

I tried these methods but so far nothing has worked:

1. Using RODBC
2. Using GET() and paste the url
3. Using quantmod or any packages that relates to fetching data